# Is it possible to use input box to select a row from excel sheet and then select specific cell values from that row to fill in rest of VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am learning to use VBA to make a PPT from excel. I have written the whole function but wanted to make it easier for a user to use it. So, I wanted to see if its possible if I create an input box where the user add the row number and then specific cells from that row are selected to add values in PPT.

For example, lets say the user put "208" in the input box and the values in cell B208, I208, J208 are used in the function as shown below.

```
 ppSlide.Select
    Range("B208").Copy
    ppSlide.Shapes.Paste
    With pppres.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
        .Top = 30
    End With

    ppSlide.Select
    Range("I208").Copy
    ppSlide.Shapes.Paste
    With pppres.Slides(1).Shapes(2)
        .Left = 140
        .Top = 73
    End With

    ppSlide.Select
    Range("J208").Copy
    ppSlide.Shapes.Paste
    With pppres.Slides(1).Shapes(3)
        .Left = 480
        .Top = 73
    End With
```

So instead of changing values at 15-16 different spots a user can just add it in the input box once. and dont have to mess with the code.

Comment: Yes this is possible. Have you tried it yet, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Right now I can only a specific cell and cant figure out how to select multiple cells from one value in input box

Comment: You can assign the `textbox` value to a variable, and then define each range to the column and variable, e.g. `Dim InputRowNumber As Long` then `InputRowNumber = TextBox1.Text` then `Range("B" & InputRowNumber)`. I'd need to know more info such as is the textbox on the sheet or a userform, will the user click a button to make this work etc to be able to provide a suitable answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you have in mind - more or less. Please take a look.

```
Sub TestPPslide()

    Dim ppPres As Object                    ' which type of object?
    Dim ppSlide As Object                   ' which data type?
    Dim Inp As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    R = 2
    Do
        Inp = InputBox("Enter a valid row number.", "Slide selector", R)
        ' test if Inp is valid
        If IsNumeric(Inp) Then
            R = Int(Val(Inp))
            If R > 1 And R < 100 Then Exit Do
        Else
            If Len(Inp) = 0 Then Exit Sub       ' user presserd cancel
        End If
    Loop

    SetSlide R, ppSlide, ppPres.Slides(1)
End Sub

Private Function SetSlide(ByVal R As Long, _
                          ppSlide As Object, _
                          PresSlide As Object) As Boolean

    Dim Clm As Variant
    Dim Left As Variant, Top As Variant
    Dim C As Long

    Clm = Array("B", "I", "J")
    Left = Array(0, 140, 480)
    Top = Array(30, 73, 73)

    For C = 0 To UBound(Clm)
        Cells(R, Clm(C)).Copy
        ppSlide.Shapes.Paste
        With PresSlide.Shapes(C + 1)
            .Left = Left(C)
            .Top = Top(C)
        End With
    Next C
End Function
```

I don't know what your objects are, whether they are from Excel or from PP. Therefore I may not handle these objects correctly. Or there may be some inconsistencies in your own code in their regard. Take my code as a guide to how to set it up.

1. Create a `Main` with sub procedures and functions. Dont just concatenate one thought after the other into a single procedure.
2. The `Main` must contain the input for the task. Then it must hand the job off to the next procedure which, in this case, feeds back the two objects the sub `SetSlide` modified for further attention by the `Main` or perhaps the next sub routine.
3. Avoid `Select` or `Activate`. You can access every part of every object without such action.